# How to Secure HTML Application (HTA)?

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have created one GUI using below code in HTA:

```
Sub result ( )
    Dim strComputer, objShell, objExec, strPingResults, WshShell
strComputer = Trim( UCase( ComputerNameTextBox.Value ) )
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set objExec = WshShell.Exec("cmd.exe /c  C: \Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware vSphere CLI\bin & esxcli -s "&strComputer&" -u root -p NTMC_Admin network nic list ")
        strPingResults = LCase(objExec.StdOut.ReadAll)
        ResultsTextArea.Value = ""

        ResultsHiddenText.Value = strComputer   & vbTab
        ResultsHiddenText.Value = strComputer & vbcr & vblf & strPingResults
        ResultsTextArea.Value = ResultsTextArea.Value & strPingResults   
        CopyButton.Disabled = False
        ResetButton.Disabled = False

    ' change mouse pointer back to default
    Document.Body.Style.Cursor = "default"
End Sub
```

Please help me out to secure my code so that no one can see the this function under any view source.

Comment: please add tag(s) for the language of the code snipped (VBScript?)

Answer (score 1):

You should try to convert your vbscript and your HTA to executables files !

**[(VbsEdit/HTAEdit)](http://www.vbsedit.com)**, it's a package includes (VbsEdit 32-bit, VbsEdit 64-bit, HtaEdit 32-bit and HtaEdit 64-bit). has a good feature is to compile and convert your vbs or your HTA files into **.exe** and it is totaly free.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't help much, all the files are extracted during execution, and the source code will be available again.

Comment: @Teemu Did you tried with this soft HTAEdit ? or other ? and can you explain more how i will get the source code and from what path ?

Comment: Yes, a couple of years ago. And all them (HTA converters) are working in the same way.

Comment: @Teemu I invite you to test it only with this soft (HTAEdit) and give me after you feedback ;)
Thank you !

Comment: I'm not sure, if I'm allowed to re-install HTAEdit. But if you have it installed, you can very well open a folder, where you've an HTA.exe saved, with Windows Resource Manager, then run that exe, and you'll see, how it will create and save temporary extracts of the files within exe. Notice, that those extracts might be saved also somewhere else, you can select a folder for them when creating the package.

Answer (score 0):

hta_code.exe extract All resources And HTA either Into Temp folder Of System Or User specified Folder.u can easily reach temp folder while hta is running and copy extracted folder to a safe location because after Hta been closed Extracted command in .exe Delete all files from temp folder.to locate hta in temp folder we can use window search by typing .hta............@teemu is right @hackoo m not sure about htaedit but i will check this out today